# Where to store version for .NET core project for NuGet packaging, etc

Tags: nuget, teamcity, version, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm using TeamCity to build and publish my .NET core application to NuGet.

I've been using the project.json file for storing the version, but with the latest version of .NET core the project.json file has become obsolete, since everything has moved to the project's .csproj file. So I'm trying to find a new home for the version information.

Here are some possibilities that I can think of.

1. Continue using project.json, but only for storing the version information (doesn't feel like a permanent solution)
2. Storing the version in a separate file like `version.txt`
3. Somehow storing it in GitHub using tags or something alike. This feels like the ideal solution.

I like option 3. the most, e.g. for storing release points (1.0, 2.0, etc.) and then using some date time appended afterwards. But I'm unsure if that's possible or even recommended.

What is the recommended way of storing the version information, given that you have your project in GitHub and that you're using the latest .NET core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a problem with having it in the .csproj file?

As for recommendations - there are various ways you do this which you choose is up to you.

With .NET Core the assembly information can be specified in the project file (.csproj). How you have it defined in the project file is up to you.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.4</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You could have it hard coded. Or run some other MSBuild task to generate it.

AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion should work in the same way.

When you build the project an AssemblyInfo.cs file is generated in the `obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/` directory.

Comment: No problem at all, I just wasn't aware that it was possible. This seems like the easiest and best place to do it for now. A part of me still wants to look into using GitHub tagging for versioning. Thanks.